# what "balance" used for in TDengine database

Tags: tdengine

there is a configuration parameter "balance" in /etc/taos/taos.cfg, the default value is 1, I am wondering what is it and how to use it?

```
# enable/disable load balancing
# balance                   1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TDengine's data is distributed on different vnodes. After a long time, there may be uneven data distribution. At this time, this switch can be used to automatically migrate data on different vnodes to achieve balanced distribution.